# Neo4j configure path to java 8

Tags: neo4j

How do you configure neo4j default path java_home to some other path?
The current server has java 6 installed and some applications depend on it. I need to configure neo4j to java 8 folder without changing the java_home. How do I do this?

Comment: Whilst I am unable to answer this question, you should post what you have tried so far to have a better chance of getting a good answer, and also minimizing the risk of getting flagged.

Answer (score 1):

While you could try and fix all the scripts that depend on JAVA_HOME :

- installation_directory/bin/* on Linux
- installation_directory\bin\Neo4j-Management\Get-Java.ps1 on Windows

your best bet i.m.o is to override JAVA_HOME in the session where you start Neo4j. If you're using the package installations on Linux, you should set the JAVA_HOME override in the environment of the **neo4j** user (that should not impact other softwares).

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

P.S. The fact that you are running **other** applications on the same machine as Neo4j may not be a good idea if we're talking about a production environment (it's not a good idea for any environment in fact).

Comment: How do you override JAVA_HOME when you start Neo4j?

Comment: with "export JAVA_HOME = " on Linux, "set JAVA_HOME=" on Windows ? If you're using the packages (and thus user neo4j) set it in the profile